# PHP - Get start and end date of current date interval

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have as unix timestamps

```
$now         = strtotime("2013-12-10");
$start_date  = strtotime("2013-01-01");
$end_date    = strtotime("2013-12-31");
```

The `$start date` and `$end date` span a period of time and the `$now` timestamp sits in the middle of the two.

I also have a variable date interval like so:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');
// or
$interval = new DateInterval('P3D');
```

Given the above how do I get the start and end timestamps of the interval that `now` sits in?
The `$now`, `$start_date`, `$end_date` and the interval will be dynamic.

**Example**

Lets say I have these parameters:

```
$start_date = '2013-01-01 00:00:00';
$end_date   = '2013-12-31 23:59:59';
$now        = '2013-12-10 15:45:34';
$interval   = new DateInterval( 'P1W' );
```

I want to know the start and end date of the interval $now sits in. The output I would expect from the above params is:

```
$int_start_date = '2013-12-10 00:00:00';
$int_end_date   = '2013-12-16 23:59:59';
```

Comment: read this manual for php function `date` and you'll know what to do: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I've read the manual many times but I cannot come up with a solution to my problem hence why I'm asking here.

Comment: Are you saying that you know the value of $now and you need to find the values of $start_date and $end_date given that $now is the middle date of a 4 week period?

Comment: You say "Lets say the start date and end date span 4 weeks" and then you say " I would expect the start date to be the start of week 2 and the end date to be the end of week 2" which is 1 week. Can you clarify what it is you're asking?

Comment: I don't get it. Could you give us an example of the result you are expecting?

Comment: Another example added

Comment: You wan't to know what week $now is in? ie the date of Monday and the date of Sunday?

Comment: @vascowhite No. I want to know the start and end date of the interval $now sits in. I don't know how I can be any clearer. In my examples I have set the interval to 1 week but it could be anything from an interval of 1 minute to 1 year.

Comment: Your latest example shows $now as 1 day later than the start of the interval, but earlier you said it should be in the middle. We are trying to help you here, but the onus is on you to explain the problem clearly. Obviously you are not doing that, or you would have an answer by now.

Comment: How do you know where $now sits in relation to $int_start_date and $int_end_date?

Comment: @Brady The DateInterval object has no knowledge of the beginning/end of a week/month/year and for weeks at least, some people consider Monday to be the start, whereas others consider Sunday. I'll update my answer with an alternative solution that doesn't rely on DateInterval in case you're not reliant on that specific implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a less hacky and cleaner approach than yours.

```
$start_date    = new DateTime( '2013-01-01 00:00:00' );
$end_date      = new DateTime( '2013-12-31 23:59:59' );
$end_date_ts   = $end_date->getTimestamp();
$now           = new DateTime( '2013-12-10 15:45:34' );
$now_ts        = $now->getTimestamp();
$interval      = new DateInterval( 'P1W' );
$periods        = new DatePeriod( $start_date, $interval, $end_date );

/** @var \DateTime $period */
foreach($periods as $period){
    $periodEnd = clone $period;
    $periodEnd->add($interval);
    if($period < $now && $now < $periodEnd){
        $result = iterator_to_array(new \DatePeriod($period, $interval, $periodEnd->add($interval)));
        $int_start_date = $result[0];
        $int_end_date = $result[1];
        break;
    }
}

/** @var DateTime $int_start_date */
/** @var DateTime $int_end_date */
var_dump( $int_start_date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
var_dump( $int_end_date->modify( '-1 Second' )->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
```

Comment: while I agree this is less hacky than my solution it doesn't take into account the minus 1 second on the interval end date. I'm using this to report against events in a database so if an event happens at 00:00:00 it will appear in two intervals

Comment: To fix I would say the last line should be: `var_dump( $int_end_date->modify('-1 Second')->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );`

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Feel free to modify it as you see fit for your use case. I'm glad we got there in the end :)

Comment: I've also added a break; to the if statement. If we find the interval we can bail and forget processing the rest.

Comment: The way to deal with that is to put the whole thing in a function and return once you've found the interval.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$now = time();
$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');

$interval_seconds = $interval->s + ($interval->i * 60) + ($interval->h * 60 * 60) + ($interval->d * 60 * 60 * 24);
$half_interval = round($interval_seconds / 2);

// Unix timestamps
$interval_start = $now - $half_interval;
$interval_end = $now + $half_interval;
```

**EDIT: 2nd answer following on from comments**

This only works for intervals of length 1 - eg 1 week, 1 year etc.

If your interval is > 1 then you'll need to somehow determine how far through the interval you are... e.g for a 2 week interval, are you in the first week or the second week?

```
$now = time();

$interval = "week";

switch ($interval) {
    case "year":
        $start_int = strtotime(date("Y", $now)."-01-01 00:00:00");
        $end_int = strtotime(date("Y", $now)."-12-31 23:59:59");
    break;
    case "month":
        $start_int = strtotime(date("Y-m", $now)."-01 00:00:00");
        $end_int = strtotime(date("Y-m-t", $now)." 23:59:59");
    break;
    case "week":
        $start_week = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("previous Monday", $now));
        $end_week = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("next Sunday", $now));

        $start_int = strtotime($start_week." 00:00:00");
        $end_int = strtotime($end_week." 23:59:59");
    break;
    case "day":
        $start_int = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $now)." 00:00:00");
        $end_int = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $now)." 23:59:59");
    break;
    case "hour":
        $start_int = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H", $now).":00:00");
        $end_int = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H", $now).":59:59");
    break;
    case "minute":
        $start_int = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i", $now).":00");
        $end_int = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i", $now).":59");
    break;
}
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start_int), "<br>";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $end_int), "<br>";
```

**Update 3**

I've put the logic from your answer into a single loop:

```
$start_date    = new DateTime( '2013-01-01 00:00:00' );
$end_date      = new DateTime( '2013-12-31 23:59:59' );
$end_date_ts   = $end_date->getTimestamp();
$now           = new DateTime( '2013-12-10 15:45:34' );
$now_ts        = $now->getTimestamp();
$interval      = new DateInterval( 'P1W' );
$period        = new DatePeriod( $start_date, $interval, $end_date );

$int_start_date = $start_date;
$int_end_date   = $end_date;

foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
    $timestamp = $dt->getTimestamp();

    if ($now_ts >= $timestamp) {
        $int_start_date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
    }
    if ($now_ts < $timestamp and $timestamp < $int_end_date->getTimestamp()) {
        $int_end_date->setTimestamp($timestamp - 1);
    }
}
var_dump( $int_start_date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
var_dump( $int_end_date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured the problem myself however is hacky

```
$start_date    = new DateTime( '2013-01-01 00:00:00' );
$end_date      = new DateTime( '2013-12-31 23:59:59' );
$end_date_ts   = $end_date->getTimestamp();
$now           = new DateTime( '2013-12-10 15:45:34' );
$now_ts        = $now->getTimestamp();
$interval      = new DateInterval( 'P1W' );
$period        = new DatePeriod( $start_date, $interval, $end_date );

$intervals = array();

foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
    $intervals[] = $dt->getTimestamp();
}

$intervals[]    = $end_date_ts;
$int_start_date = new DateTime();
$int_end_date   = new DateTime();

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $intervals ); $i++ ) {
    if ( $now_ts >= $intervals[$i] && $now_ts <= $intervals[$i+1]) {
        $int_start_date->setTimestamp($intervals[$i]);
        $int_end_date->setTimestamp($intervals[$i+1]-1);
            break;
    }
}

var_dump( $int_start_date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
var_dump( $int_end_date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
```

I gladly accept better approaches if anyone has them.

Comment: I just ran that code, and for the dates given you get a result of Tuesday 10th Dec 2013 as the start, and Monday 16th Dec 2013 as the end. Just out of interest, is that the correct solution? I would have expected the 9th to the 15th (or 8th to 14th).

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your approach but with only one loop in it, rather than two.

Comment: I've provided what I think is a less 'hacky' solution, you opinion may be different :)

Comment: @Jon The overall start date starts on a Tuesday so I expect each interval of 1 week to start on Tuesday. With that I also expect the interval end date to end on a Monday at 23:59:59 so not to recount the same second on the next interval